# wrapping divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I need to wrap some divs into another div with jQuery, the original output looks like this:

```
<div>Some content</div>
<div>Some content</div>

<h3>Local</h3>
<div>Some content</div>
<div>Some content</div>
<div>Some content</div>

<h3>Non-Local</h3>
<div>Some content</div>
<div>Some content</div>
<div>Some content</div>
```

And I would need to wrap them so they look like this:

```
<div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Local</h3>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Local</h3>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

The divs can't be identified by any id or class, so I would need to find a way to wrap all divs that follow an h3.

Comment: Right, and what have you tried?

Comment: This is really something that should be sorted out server side to be honest

Comment: @Sam I wish, the code is generated by a CMS (drupal) and I can't really change it

Comment: @woutr_be I am pretty good with drupal, can you edit a template file to sort your code out? Or can you explain how/where this code is generated?

Comment: @Sam It's a view that uses grouping, but sadly it doesn't wrap the group objects, it just sorts them.

Comment: @woutr_be In your view have you created a node-view-VIEWNAME.tpl.php? You should be able to style whats being pulled through then

Comment: @Sam I didn't create a specific template for the view, was hoping I would be able to do it without, but even with creating a view, I'm clueless on how to wrap them, I would still have to somehow to be able to identify them

Comment: @woutr_be Normally you would need to use templates to style the content coming through. Its more something that you would need to pay someone to do if you aren't so sure yourself.

Comment: @Sam Ok, for jQuery I figured out I can pull all the divs into an array and then check wether they come behind an h3, seems a bit overkill, but for now the only way to do it. I'll look into the template solution though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

- loop over the h3 elements
- use the [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) - function of jQuery to look for div elements following the h3,
- add them to the collection
- push each of them into the group array
- and then loop over the groups, and wrap each of them inside a div

  var groups = [];

  $('h3').each(function(index, value) {

  $head = $(value);

  var $group = $head.add($head.nextUntil('h3', 'div'));
    groups.push($group);

  });

  for (group in groups) {

  $(groups[group]).wrapAll('');

  }

The reason to save the groups in a groups array first is, to not change the HTML structure until having looped over each collection. Otherwise, the subsequent calls will find the added elements as well.

[Here's the example code](http://jsbin.com/umecab/1/edit).

Comment: That worked perfectly, it only didn't wrapper the first 2 divs, where there is no h3, but I figured out how to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Theorically jQuery functions "next()" or "nextAll()" or "nextUntill()" allow you to find the following sibling(s) of a selected element. So you could try something with thoose function depending of the structure of your html.

More help in jQuery doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) in the jQuery API doc.